# Concatenate the words of two strings

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

I have two strings, need to concatenate the **0th** position of **string a** with **0th** position of **string b**.

Please see the output format.

```
a='Python is a programming language'

b='We have to practice'

# Need output in the format as below

Python We

is have

a to

programming practice

language
```

```
a='Python is a programming language'
b='We have to practice'
a=a.split()
b=b.split()
c=''
print(a)
print(b)
for i in a:
  for j in b:
    c=i+' '+j
  print(c)
```

Got below output

```
Python practice

is practice

a practice

programming practice

language practice
```

Comment: please don't add language specific tags as your question isn't exclusive to a specific python version. also, is numpy/pandas being used anywhere or can be used for the solution?

Comment: to address the problem itself, the problem is the nested loop, iterates over every word in B for each word in A, whereas you want to iterate over pairs of (word_A, word_B) in one loop.

Comment: documentation of `zip` https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip

Answer (score 2):

One of the options is [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) :

```
from itertools import zip_longest
​
pairs = zip_longest(a.split(), b.split(), fillvalue="")
​
wrap = "\n".join([" ".join(pair) for pair in pairs]) # optional
```

​
Output :

```
for pair in pairs:
    print(*pair)

#or print(wrap)
​
Python We
is have
a to
programming practice
language
```